# jquery autocomplete with JSON data from a generic handler

Tags: jquery, asp.net, generics, autocomplete, handler

I have three asp.net textbox controls on a page. One of them needs to have autocomplete functionality. When user selects an item, the other two text boxes should be populated with appropriate values.

For example: Let's say the first text box is City. The user selects a City from the autocomplete list, the second should automatically be populated with the State and the third should automatically be populated with the country.

I am calling a generic asp.net handler. I am calling a database and retrieving data from three columns of a table. I am using the JavascriptSerializer to serialize the output string to JSON. So (for example) my JSON result is as such:

[{"City":"Toronto","Province":"Ontario","Country":"Canada"}]

I have been unable to figure out how to parse the JSON data I get. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: response[0].city. did you try like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the JQuery [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method, it should be parsed automatically for you.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    alert(json[0].City);
});
```

> Toronto

If you're getting a normal text response then use `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse(data)[0].City
```

**Note** This assumes the server side is correct, returning plain text with content-type header = **application/JSON**.